# How do I check if an object's class equals a value's class in an enum?

Tags: java, enums

Say in Java I have a `public enum RecyclerViewItems`.

In this enum, I have various names, LOADING, HEADER, IMAGE, etc, which I can access like `RecyclerViewItems.LOADING`, etc.

I add multiple enums into a List, `list.add(RecyclerViewItems.LOADING)` and `list.add(RecyclerViewItems.HEADER)`. I then want to check at a certain position i, if the Object in the List is either a `RecyclerViewItems.LOADING` OR `RecyclerViewItems.HEADER`.

However, I can't just do `return items.get(position) instanceof RecyclerViewItems.LOADING;` because `LOADING` is not a valid class. However if I just do `return items.get(position) instanceof RecyclerViewItems` it's going to return true for both `LOADING` and `HEADER`. So I need some way to check that the enum is, in fact, LOADING and not HEADER which are all in the same enum class.

How do I do that?

Comment: You can compare enum items with `==`

Answer (score 0):

You can compare enum value directly with `==`

You should use:

`return items.get(position) == RecyclerViewItems.LOADING`